R: Assign column value based on range of values found in columns in another dataframe
For simplicity, in dataframe 1 I have 3 genes (a, b, and c) and their positions in the genome. For instance, gene "a" starts at position 1 (min) and ends at 2 (max). In dataframe 2, I have a mutation's position, which may occur in the a gene (between df1$min and df1$max) and impact it:
df1 = data.frame("gene" = c("a","b","c"), "min" = c(1,3,5), "max"=c(2,4,6))
df2 = data.frame("position" = c(1.5,3.5,5.5),"impact" = c("low","low","high"))

I would like to make a dataframe which shows the mutation position, the gene it is in, and it's impact. Like so:
position  gene     impact
1.5       a        low
3.5       b        low
5.5       c        high

Thank you.

Here is a base R option
transform(
  df2,
  gene = with(
    df1,
    {
      d <- outer(position, min, ">=") & outer(position, max, "<=")
      c(NA, gene)[1 + rowSums(d * col(d))]
    }
  )
)

which gives
  position impact gene
1      1.5    low    a
2      3.5    low    b
3      5.5   high    c

where c(NA, gene)[1 + rowSums(d * col(d))] was applied in case no matched gene was found.

Perfect, thank you!

Or using dplyr and a non-equi join:
df2 |>
  left_join(df1, join_by(position >= min, position <= max))


  position impact gene min max
1      1.5    low    a   1   2
2      3.5    low    b   3   4
3      5.5   high    c   5   6

add |> select(-(min:max)) to remove those last two columns...
